# error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am having trouble getting my homework assignment to work properly. I have overloaded my '==' operator, but still I get this error. Not really sure why it's being thrown or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my algorithm:

```
/* Performs a recursive binary search on the given array. It returns
 * the index of the found value, -1 otherwise. 
 */
template <typename T, typename V>
int binarySearch(T* list[], const V& searchValue,
                 const int firstIndex, const int lastIndex) 
{ 
    if (firstIndex <= lastIndex) 
    {
        int mid = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;  //mid point of list.
        if (searchValue == *list[mid]) 
            return mid;   // found value.
        else if (searchValue < *list[mid]) 
            return binarySearch(list, firstIndex, mid - 1, searchValue);
        else
            return binarySearch(list, mid + 1, lastIndex, searchValue);
    }
    return -1;    //failed to find value
}
```

Debugger says this line in main is where the error originates:

```
// Search the person array.
cout << "Searching people array for person with name = 'Mickey Mouse': "
     << (binarySearch(person, "Mickey Mouse", 0, 7) != -1? "found it." : "did not find it.")
     << endl;
```

Here is my person class header file showing the overloaded operator:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace P03 {
class Person {...}; // end Person


/* Displays a Person to the screen.
 * Calls the toString() method.
 */
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Person& person)
{
    return out << person.toString();
}

/* The following relational operators compare two instances of the
 * Person class. The comparison is made on the compound value of:
 * <lastName><space><firstName>
 */
bool operator ==(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs)
{
    return lhs.getName() == rhs.getName();
}

    /*other operators*/
    ...

} // end namespace P03

#endif
```

Not sure if more of my code is needed. I will update if need be.

Comment: I added a new operator to my Person class header file: 
`bool operator ==(const char*& lhs, const Person& rhs)
 {
  return lhs == rhs.getName();
 }`

I am still getting the same error. Perhaps I am misunderstanding some of the answers you have given me.

Answer (score 3):

When you call

```
binarySearch(person, "Mickey Mouse", 0, 7)
```

In `binarySearch`, `T` the type of which `person` is an array of pointers, and `V` is `const char*`. Then in the body you do

```
searchValue == *list[mid]
```

Which is `const char*& == *person[x]`, which is why you get the error since there's no `operator==(const char*, X)` where `X` is whatever `*person[x]` is.

Comment: Actually, `person` is an array of `T*`, not just `T`.  But the essence of this answer appears correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your template class is for types `T` and `V`.  In your `binarySearch` function, you take a list of type `T` and a search value of type `V`.  You then compare them: `if (searchValue == *list[mid])`.  This is where the error is, because you probably have not implemented an `==` operator for class `T` which takes in an argument of type `V`.

The problem can be traced back to your `cout`, where you pass in `Person` as type `T` and a `const char*` as type `V`.  Your `Person` class' `==` operator only takes in a right-hand operand also of type `Person`.  In other words, in the expression `a == b`, `b` must be the `Person` type.

Answer (score 0):

The line `if (searchValue == *list[mid])` compares the types const V& with a T.
V is a C-string (`char*`), and assuming that person is an array of `Person*` T is a `Person`. You have provided a `const Person&, const Person&` comparison operator, but the code expects a  `const char*&, const Person` comparison operator. Either provide such an operator, or create a Person from the string in the `binarySearch(person, "Mickey Mouse", 0, 7)` expression.